# Three.js: Do I have to set up the anisotropic texture filtering for each texture?

Tags: three.js

Do I have to set up the anisotropic texture filtering for each texture?
I think it would be cool If you can set the anisotropic level for a material or even for the global scene. Any Ideas?

```
maxA = renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();

var texture1 = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('models/folder/m67/o1.jpg');
texture1.anisotropy = maxA;

var texture2 = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('models/folder/m67/o2.jpg');
texture2.anisotropy = maxA;

var texture3 = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('models/folder/m67/c1.jpg');
texture3.anisotropy = maxA;

var texture4 = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('models/folder/m67/c2.jpg');
texture4.anisotropy = maxA;

var material = {
  "logoprint": new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    map: texture1
  }),
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can wrap the load into a function, imageutils just gives you another utility function

```
function loadTexture( url ){
    var tex = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(url);
    tex.anisotropy = MAXANISO;
    return tex;
}
```

To clarify what's happening here, and what to do about the ImageUtils depreciation warning:

```
var tl = new THREE.TextureLoader();

//calling load on it immediately returns a THREE.Texture object
var myTexture = tl.load( 'name.jpg' );

//you can also pass a callback
function onTextureLoaded( tex ){

    //tex.image contains data, because textureLoader updated it, before passing it to the callback
    handleTexture( tex )...
}
var myTexture = tl.load( 'name.jpg' , onTextureLoaded );

// myTexture is now an instance of THREE.Texture
// myTexture.image contains no data

myTexture.aniso = ...; //texture is configured , but probably waiting for data
```

The texture object itself holds all these 3d properties like wrapping, mapping type and filtering. The image data itself has nothing to do with this, it stays the same regardless of how you use it. 
When you call load on the texture loader, it gives you back a proxy - a reference to an object that can be configured, manipulated, and passed to other objects (like materials) to be used. 
A material can render an empty texture. When the image data is loaded, the texture is updated and the very next frame will reflect that.

```
 var tl = new THREE.TextureLoader()

 function myCustomLoad( url ){
     var newTex = tl.load(url); //make the proxy
     newTex.prop = ... ;//config
     return newTex; //return configured texture, it will update itself 
}
```

Comment: What version of Three.js are you running?

Comment: just use loadTexture instead of textureLoader.loadTexture

Comment: you are still loading the texture with just the texture loader correct, youre not using the new function?